# Generator Recursion in Sieve of Eratosthenes Skips Steps

Tags: python, recursion, generator, sieve-of-eratosthenes, generator-expression

I ran into an issue with the sieve algorithm I have written here. I have tried to fix it for a total of about 10 hours now. I've looked around here for similar questions but I can't seem to find anyone who has had this issue. I'm relatively new to python, and after reading through a lot of generator documentation, I managed to write code that does work. However, I still don't know why my first attempts failed.

All I've come up with is that it seems that gen1 was not actually being emptied out during each successive sieve step. So, I tried alternating between the names gen1 and gen2, deleting each one to avoid this issue. That didn't work either.

I'd really appreciate some insight into this, and any suggestions for improving what I have now.

Here is the failed code:

```
def primes(n):
    "yields primes up to n. For use with large n"
    q = 0
    yield 2
    gen1 = (x for x in range(3,n,2))
    while q*q < n:
        q = next(gen1)
        gen1 = (x for x in gen1 if x%q != 0)
        yield q
    else:
        while 1:
            try:
                yield next(gen1)
            except:
                StopIteration
                break
```

Here is my current code:

```
import math
global gen1
global gen
def gen1(x):
    for i in range(3,x,2):
        yield i
def gen(generator,n):
    "Input generator and current starting 'index' for the generator"
    # Recursively defines new generator for sieve of Eratosthenes
    for i in range(n+1):
        predicate = next(generator)
        yield predicate
    for i in generator:
        if i % predicate != 0:
            yield i
def primes(n):
    yield 2
    a = gen1(n)
    for i in range(math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))):
        a = gen(a,i)
    yield from a
```

Comment: Once you fix your late-binding issue, be aware that that's still not a sieve; [it's trial division](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf).

Comment: @user2357112 How so? It should be sieving by non-divisibility of successive primes and shrinking the new generator each time by the factor (predicate-1)/(predicate). Correct me if I'm wrong; I do not have much experience with generators.

Comment: The sieve of Eratosthenes doesn't need to test divisibility. It skips right to the multiples of each prime. Testing divisibility, like what you're doing, is much, much slower. Even ignoring the absolute cost of a single divisibility test, the *number* of divisibility tests scales much worse than the amount of work the sieve of Eratosthenes does. This is made even worse by not stopping trial division at the square root of the numbers being tested.

Comment: The linked article goes into a lot more detail.

Comment: @user2357112 I see what you're saying now. No wonder it's so slow, haha. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic problem is one of scope.  In this line:

```
  gen1 = (x for x in gen1 if x%q != 0)
```

the value of `q` used is *not* the value `q` was bound to at the time the generator expression was *created*, but rather the (ever-changing!) value of `q` at the time the generator expression is *executing*.  This works the same way as for referencing non-local variables in any kind of nested function.

To capture bindings at creation time, the obvious and easy way is to write a function instead, and pass the values you want it to use.  For example, this rewrite is more Pythonic in that and several other respects:

```
def primes(n):
    "yields primes up to n. For use with large n"

    def gen(gen1, q):
        for x in gen1:
            if x % q:
                yield x

    q = 0
    yield 2
    gen1 = iter(range(3, n, 2))
    while q*q < n:
        q = next(gen1)
        gen1 = gen(gen1, q)
        yield q
    yield from gen1
```

Now the values used in the body of `gen()` are precisely those passed to it, so it's obvious instead of a mystery ;-)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain! That makes sense :)

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm looking for an explanation about "Now is better than never. Although never is often better than *right* now.", in the Zen of Python (2004). Al Sweigart proposes an explanation based on infinite loops (first line) and erroneous quick answer (line 2), but it doesn't seem good enough to me. Is there more to be learned 
about my ignorance here?